# can not install any snap package

Tags: unity, snap

I am trying to install libreoffice using snap, but getting error

```
$ sudo snap install libreoffice
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Fetch and check assertions for snap "core" (888) (Get https://assertions.ubuntu.com/v1/assertions/snap-revision/rwKPLzTZoPvDmaNtGAnlCau6Eljsn-FdmY_Ie8t3nJC8H659hXo7q563EN3H9L-q?max-format=0: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers))
```

I am using ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks
Aniruddha

Comment: Looks like a temporary network issue, or you're behind a proxy of some kind. Can you try again or confirm whether you're behind a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Try again - the server is ready for download now. But use:

```
 **sudo snap install libreoffice --stable**
```